# dynamic searchable fields, best practice?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Lexicon model, and I want user to be able to create dynamic feature to every lexicon.

And I have a complicate search interface that let user search on every single feature (including the dynamic ones) belonged to Lexicon model.

I could have used a serialized text field to save all the dynamic information if they are not for searching.

In case I want to let user search on all fields, I have created a DynamicField Model to hold all dynamically created features.

But imagine I have 1,000,000,000 lexicon, and if one create a dynamic feature for every lexicon, this will result creating 1,000,000,000 rows in DynamicField model.

So the sql search function will become quite inefficient while a lot of dynamic features created.

Is there a better solution for this situation?

Which way should I take?

1. searching for a better db design for dynamic fields
2. try to tuning mysql(add cache fields, add index ...) with current db design

Comment: 1. How does your DB tables (or Rails models) look right now? Maybe a code snapshot? 2. What kind of queries do you want to support? (EQUALS, IN, NOT IN, LIKE, GREATER THAN, etc.)

Comment: The design pattern you might want to go with is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model

Comment: Ordinary, the type of search I want implement is LIKE, LESS THAN, GREATER THAN, IN, EQUALS, NOT IN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another idea might be to use [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) and [MongoMapper](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/06/27/mongomapper-the-rad-mongo-wrapper/), [Thinking Sphinx](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/) or [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/). Here is Railscast on how to use Mongo: http://railscasts.com/episodes/194-mongodb-and-mongomapper

Comment: I am looking at mongodb now. I will post an update if I find a decent solution.
Thanks for relpy

Comment: Cool, I've used Solr in the past but its really difficult to setup, especially on a linux box so I think MongoDB is supposed to be very rails friendly.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do this is to use a name/value pairing instead of dynamic fields. Let me explain using the [EAV design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model)

So instead of having something like this:

```
Table: MedicalRecords
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Temperature in degrees Fahrenheit</th>
    <th>Presence of Cough</th>
    <th>Type of Cough</th>
    <th>Heart Rate in beats per minute</th>
    <th>Column X</th>
    <th>Column X + 1</th>
    <th>... Column N</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>102</td>
    <td>True</td>
    <td>With phlegm, yellowish, streaks of blood</td>
    <td>98</td>
    <td>????</td>
    <td>????</td>
    <td>????</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You would design your table like this:

```
Table: MedicalRecords
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Temperature in degrees Fahrenheit</td>
    <td>102</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Presence of Cough</td>
    <td>True</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Type of Cough</td>
    <td>With phlegm, yellowish, streaks of blood</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Heart Rate in beats per minute</td>
    <td>98</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Column X</td>
    <td>????</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Column X + 1</td>
    <td>????</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>... Column N</td>
    <td>????</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

(Tried to get the table tags to work but couldn't Try coping my code into an html file to get the idea.)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation on EAV design pattern.


I just read that wiki page you gave me on this topic, and got a little idea of it.


What I want to ask is how to implement the EAV design pattern in a traditional db(the relational db)?


Or I think the mongodb itself has already implemented that EAV design pattern internally, am I right here?

Comment: Use this example as a way to do it in a relational database, but use MongoDB for posting XML (a perfect example of dynamic data defintion) to the MongoDB. If MongoDB is anything like Solr or Thinking Sphinx, you will be able to do very complex searching against it.

For example, if you have a products database but the products have different attributes (books have pages, laptops have battery life etc) you can use a special query language to return the results you want. Here is an example of hose Solr does it: http://lucene.apache.org/solr/tutorial.html